# PHP syntax - shows text and not link

Tags: php, html

With this snippet of code, I'm attempting to show a clickable link (if "admin" is logged in), which will redirect me to adminarea.php

Right now it just prints out "Admin" in text. Nothing to click on. Just simple text.

Am I missing anything? Surely I got it wrong but I cannot see what's missing.

Here is the code:

```
<?php if (getUser("user") == "admin") { ?>
    <option value="adminarea.php">Admin</option>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: <a href="adminarea.php">Admin</a>

Comment: *"and not link"* - Link, what link? View your HTML source, what does it reveal?... *exactly?* You'll see that `<option value="adminarea.php">Admin</option>` is exactly what you asked it to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're printing an `option`, which is part of the `select` form input. You're probably looking for an anchor?

`<a href="adminarea.php">Admin</a>`

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a better way to do this would be to declare two options for a variable in your PHP first. Something like:

```
    <?php
    if(getUser("user") == "admin") {
    $adminlink = '<a href="adminarea.php">Admin</a>';
    } else {
    $adminlink = NULL;
    }
    ?>
```

And in the html:

```
    <?php echo $adminlink; ?>
```

This would show the href link if the PHP condition was true, and would display nothing if not. Hope this helps!

Comment: Interesting solution. This would indeed make it much easier to read. Good one.

Answer (score 0):

Well based on your title am assuming you want a link. By the way you can use PHP friend html syntax instead of making the code look "dirty".

```
<?php if(getUser("user") == "admin"): ?>
      <a href="adminarea.php">Admin</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```